# Can I call declared variable from wp.config and rewrite her value in functions.php inside custom function ?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wp-config.php folder I implemented my global variable `$argsFilter`, and in functions.php I have function on filtering my data and result must be saved in that variable, cause it will filter my data on page. Unfortunatelly, `$argsFilter` is not recognized as global variable in function. Does exist some way, how to rewrite her, please?

Comment: why you want to do that? what's the point?

Comment: Point is that page is load , I do not want to filter my Custom Post Type data,,,so $argsFilter is set on 'null', but when I want to filter, I implemented function on filterring data, and result must be saved to that variable

Comment: Could you provide a real-world example of the desired functionality for `$argsFilter` perhaps?  I'm not sure I'm fully understanding the use case here.  I wonder if using a transient might work for your needs?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API